# Integration on Maple

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the following integration

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{1} {\sqrt\pi} \sin (n\frac{(x+\pi)} {2})x^2 \frac{1} {\sqrt\pi} \sin (m\frac{(x+\pi)}{2}) dx$ $m$ and $n$ are integers,

and I used Maple to get the integration and the result is 
$\frac{(4(4(-1)^{n+m}nm+4nm)}{m^4-2m^2n^2+n^4}$

Actually, I'm not sure about the result, I dont know if there is any other way you can suggest to compute the integration rather than the integration by parts?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: You could  choose values for $m$ and $n$ and then compare the numerical integral with the floating point of the result you doubt.  Repeat until you doubt no longer.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding what you mean by, “rather than integration by parts.” Are you saying that we can’t use integration by parts?

Comment: No, I mean I don't want to use the integration by parts.

Comment: The simplest result (at least to me) is $\frac{16 m n (1+\cos (m \pi) \cos (n \pi  ))}{\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working the antiderivative, you could start rewriting the product of the sines by the differences of cosines.

Doing it, you face two integrals looking like
$$\int \cos(a x+b)\,x^2\,dx$$ Now, assume that the result is of the form $P \cos(ax+b)+Q \sin(ax+b)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials.

So, differentiating both sides
$$\cos(a x+b)\,x^2=(a Q+P') \cos(ax+b)-(aP-Q')\sin(ax+b)$$ Because of the cosine term the degree cannot be larger than $2$ for $aQ+P'$ making as a maximum $Q_2$ and $P_3$.

So, let $P=\sum_{i=0}^3 \alpha(i) x^i$ and $Q=\sum_{i=0}^2 \beta(i) x^i$ and replace.

The rhs will become
$$[(a \beta (0)+\alpha (1))+x (a \beta (1)+2 \alpha (2))+x^2 (a \beta (2)+3 \alpha
   (3))] \cos(a x+b)+$$ $$[(a \alpha (0)-\beta (1))+x (a \alpha (1)-2 \beta (2))+a \alpha (2) x^2+a \alpha (3)
   x^3] \sin(a x+b)$$ Now, identify to get the value of the coefficients and get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 i & \alpha_i &\beta_i \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{a^3} \\
 1 & \frac{2}{a^2} & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & \frac{1}{a} \\
 3 & 0 & 
\end{array}
\right)$$ making
$$\int \cos(a x+b)\,x^2\,dx=\frac{2 a x \cos (a x+b)+\left(a^2 x^2-2\right) \sin (a x+b)}{a^3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I don't believe the formula when $n$ and $m$ are equals..

Comment: @S.N.A. For sure ! But in such a case, what is the result after transforming to the difference of cosines ?

Comment: I like this, thank you very much Mr.  Claude Leibovic for your help.